# C# convert RecognizedAudio to text

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, speech-recognition

I want my program to convert my RecognizedAudio to text, this is what I have tried

```
RecognizedAudio nameAudio = result.GetAudioForWordRange(result.Words[2], result.Words[result.Words.Count - 1]);
MessageBox.Show(nameAudio.ToString());
```

It outputs this message:

> System.Speech.Recognition.RecognizedAudio

Would anybody be able to help me with this issue? I'd really appreciate it!

Thanks in advance

Comment: Apologies for my unfamiliarity in this particular library, but from the API documentation it looks like you get text from Audio via RecognitionResult.Text property which says `Gets the normalized text generated by a speech recognizer from recognized input.`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ToString()` is simply the default ToString() method of the class, and calling it actually converts it to string and it is not the method you are looking for.

From [SpeechRecognizer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.speech.recognition.speechrecognitionengine.speechrecognized?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2):

You must have add a handler for your class:

```
 static void recognizer_SpeechRecognized(object sender, SpeechRecognizedEventArgs e)  
    {  
      Console.WriteLine("Speech recognized:  " + e.Result.Text);  
      Console.WriteLine();  
      Console.WriteLine("Semantic results:");  
      Console.WriteLine("  The flight origin is " + e.Result.Semantics["origin"].Value);  
      Console.WriteLine("  The flight destination is " + e.Result.Semantics["destination"].Value);  
    }
```

The code above is the last lines of code in the page from Microsoft I have refereed.

Comment: With `MessageBox.Show(e.Result.Semantics["Search"].Value);` it gives me this error: `Argument 1: cannot convert from 'object' to 'string'`